# How to back up data from client computers to server using Windows Server 2012 R2?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8, windows-server-2012, windows-backup

Is it possible to backup data from client computers to servers using Windows Server 2012 R2? I want to backup all data in my client computers and store it on my server. I tried the Windows Server backup, but it's for local data only.

Comment: Use the windows backup tool on the clients and point it to the server!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look: http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/jj713516.aspx

**Manage backup for Windows Server 2012 Essentials client computers**

```
Set up backup for a client computer:
Open the Dashboard, and then click the Devices tab.
Click the name of the client computer that you want to set up backup for, and then in the Tasks pane, click Set up Backup for this computer.
In the Set Up Backup Wizard, you can choose to back up all of the folders or select certain folders that you want to back up. Follow the instructions in the wizard.
Click Close when backup is set up for the computer.
```

and so long ...

Comment: But I'm using R2 not Essentials

Comment: Its the same approach - just try it!